# Why are transitions not working for elements created in by react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, css-transitions

I have this css applied to elements in react

```
.my-float{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

and in my component I have

```
 {(!visibility)&&<i className="fa fa-angle-up my-float" ></i>}
 {visibility&&<i className="fa fa-times my-float" ></i>}
```

As you may see I have the ability to toggle these two elements, the challenge is the transitions are not applied. How can I make sure the transitions work? I want the elements to fade in and fade out when appearing and disappearing respectively.

Comment: `transition: 2s;` -> Here you specify either `all` or the CSS property that should be transitioned

Comment: @iamafasha: Hi There !!! I have mentioned some issues that are possibilities for your code not working :) If this solves your problem well and good. In case not then I  would suggest sharing a codesandbox project link with me .. I will try to help you out with this :)

Comment: I tried to do the changes you said there and I ended up with this. https://codesandbox.io/s/late-leaf-ewy9i

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you are adding/removing your `<i>` from DOM depending on `visibility`

So you won't have any CSS-transition if your icon is removed from DOM, or if your icon has just been added to DOM.

Your icon needs to be on DOM everytime so CSS transitions can apply

```js
<>
  <i className={`fa fa-angle-up my-float ${visibility && 'hidden'} />
  <i className={`fa fa-times my-float ${!visibility && 'hidden'} />
</>
```

Or using https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

```
import cn from 'clsx';

<>
  <i className={cn('fa fa-angle-up my-float', visibility && 'hidden')} />
  <i className={cn('fa fa-times my-float', !visibility && 'hidden'} />
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

One that `transition-property` name is missing in your CSS.

You have used.

```
transition: 2s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
```

But on what CSS-property will transition happen is missing. Try something like:

```
/* Apply to all changed properties */
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
```

Second thing is Transition is set on an element and then based on any of the event like hover or click or on load it comes into effect.

Third `my-float` class has been used in both the cases of your state.

```
 {(!visibility)&&<i className="fa fa-angle-up my-float" ></i>}
 {visibility&&<i className="fa fa-times my-float" ></i>}
```

This code can be cleaned up and `DRY principle` can be followed within the `className.`

```
<i className={`${visibility}?"fa fa-times my-float" : fa fa-angle-up my-float" `}></i>
```